# What is the meaning of bcc32?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I have installed bcc55 C++ compiler for Windows 64bit. With this, we can compile and execute C and C++ programs. My system is 64 bit OS. To compile the program in bcc55 compiler, we have to use the following command: `bcc32 fileName.c` To run the C program, we have to use `fileName`.

In this, what is the meaning of `bcc32`?

Why they have named it like this?

Why is the command not like `bcc64 fileName.c` or `bcc55 fileName.c`?

Comment: Borland C++ was a fine product back in 1990s, it was a head of its time. Unfortunately it has been out of date for the last 15 years or so. Is somebody forcing you to use it?

Comment: There are "32-bit" and "64-bit" systems out there. So I assume `bcc32` is a 32-bit compiler. Also, if bcc55 really stands for Borland C++ 5.5 released in 2000, there would be no 64-bit version. There may be 16-bit version, though. Note: this compiler is quite outdated.

Comment: Are you sure that command is compiling the program as 64-bit?  From a casual web search, I've seen mention of `bcc64.exe` too.  My guess is that bcc32 will generate a 32-bit program, which windows can run via WOW64 emulation.  To test, try writing a program that prints the value `sizeof(void*)`.  If it's 4, then your app is 32 bits.  If it's 8, your app is 64 bits.

Comment: Yes, of course i can use updated one. But i have to use it. My instructor told me to use it. sizeof(void*) printing 4. Thanks for the response guys.

Comment: @CoCo: OK, red flags all around. Find a different instructor, **now**. Don't waste your time learning an outdated version of the language. Also, if your instructor insists on such an outdated version, chances are high that instructor isn't up to par either.

Comment: @CoCo "*I have to use it. My instructor told me to use it*" - then your instructor is not doing you any good favor by making you use a 21-year-old compiler based on outdated technology.  At the very least, Embarcadero (Borland's successor) released an [updated free version](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler) of the command-line compiler a few years ago.